# View or edit MySQL Triggers using Webmin

Tags: mysql, webmin

I am using Webmin 1.470.

Am I able to view or edit MySQL triggers using it?  If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I can determine.  Use shell or install phpmyadmin for a substitute.